# Could someone help me understand using 'permit' in controller and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
     "authenticity_token"=>"mxj1M1VOCWZ5Xk79VqR6qoS6v/McZRpoXkwmhEI/i2c=",
     "event"=>{"title"=>"dshs", "organizer"=>"aha", "location"=>"afa", 
     "sdatetime"=>"2014-03-24 13:30:00.000000", 
     "edatetime"=>"2014-03-28 13:35:00.000000",
      "short_description"=>"shgshsgh", "contact_name"=>"shsh", 
      "contact_phone"=>"8989989", "email"=>"nak@isro.com", "venue"=>"aaaaaaaa", 
      "domain_ids"=>[""], "category_ids"=>["1", "3", "4", ""], 
      "eligible_ids"=>["2", "3", "4", ""], 
     "events_description"=>"<p>ssssssssssssssssssss</p>\r\n"}, 
     "url"=>"", "region"=>"india", "commit"=>"Submit Event", "id"=>"15"}

      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
      Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "15"]]
      Unpermitted parameters: domain_ids, category_ids, eligible_ids
```

So, I tried this: Event.rb

```
attr_accessible  :blahblahs,:category_ids,
                 :domain_ids, :eligible_ids
```

of course, I have this included in Event.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :domains
has_and_belongs_to_many :eligibles
```

I tried this too in events_controller

```
params.require(:event).permit(:blahblahs,:category_ids,
                 :domain_ids, :eligible_ids)
```

Problem is the model is getting updated through rails console 
          when i use `event=event.find(z)  event.category_ids=[x,y]` - It's updating the model.

I'm using check boxes for the inputs

Event controller action:

```
def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.categories.build
    @event.domains.build
    @event.eligibles.build 

  end
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
      @event.categories.build
    @event.domains.build
    @event.eligibles.build 
     @event.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end


def update

  @event = Event.find(params[:id])   
     @event.categories.build
    @event.domains.build
    @event.eligibles.build
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title,:organizer,:venue,:location,
      :short_description,:sdatetime,:edatetime,:contact_name,
                                      :contact_phone, :email,
                                     :events_description,:user_id)
    end
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Could someone help me understand using `permit` in controller and `attr_accessible` clearly?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please include your controller action in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Permit](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)
>   returns a new ActionController::Parameters instance that includes only
>   the given filters and sets the permitted attribute for the object to
>   true. This is useful for limiting which attributes should be allowed
>   for mass updating.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { name: 'Francesco', age: 22, role: 'admin' })
permitted = params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age)
permitted.permitted?      # => true
permitted.has_key?(:name) # => true
permitted.has_key?(:age)  # => true
permitted.has_key?(:role) # => false
```

[attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible)
specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment.

`attr_accessible` has been deprecated in rails 4, to access it in rails 4 you need to add [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) to your `Gemfile`

Then back to your question

change:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title,:organizer,:venue,:location,
                                :short_description, :sdatetime,:edatetime,
                                :contact_name, :contact_phone, :email,
                                :events_description,:user_id)
end
```

to:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title,:organizer,:venue,:location,
                                :short_description, :sdatetime,:edatetime,
                                :contact_name, :contact_phone, :email,
                                :events_description,:user_id,:category_ids,
                                :domain_ids, :eligible_ids)
end
```

And you should be fine

Comment: It's not working for me :( I do have protected_variables gem included in my Gemfile.

Comment: @nk06 remove `attr_accessible` from your model, and just use the `event_params` method as I have specified, and you should be fine

Comment: params.require(:event).permit(blabblahs, {:domain_ids =>[]},{:category_ids =>[]},{:eligible_ids =>[]})

This worked for my Event model!

My User model works without initiating it as an array. Crazy!

Comment: Any idea why is this happening? Feel free to edit the post. We can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is the model is getting updated through rails console when i use event=event.find(z)  event.category_ids=[x,y] - It's updating the model.

The `permit` method isn't like `attr_accessible` which stops accessing/updating the field outside model. The `permit` method whitelist the attributes which you want to set when user send request. Since, you are updating your field in console which is not coming from request params, it will update it.